# Designing facebook application

Tags: facebook

I made a canvas page and a condensed version of my website.

When a user visits the canvas I'm planning to:

Parse the signed request. Check if they are already registered by looking for their facebook id in the database:

If yes:
- Log them in. Life goes on as usual.
- Important events can be published to their page using the oauth token.

If No:
- Ask for permissions:

If granted:
- Ask if they would like to associate their facebook id with an already registered account, or create a new account.
- Save their facebook id and oauth tokens in the user database along with their account name

If not granted:
- Give them the unregistered display of the application as usual.

I don't know much about facebook so if someone can give me feedback on my idea before I start doing the dirty work that would be great.

One question I still haven't found the answer to: how can I register a link to my Canvas onto the user's page so they can easily return to the canvas?

I'm planning to use Facepy.

Answer (score 1):

your approach is correct, and i share your pain in dealing with FB documentations.

The process of asking for permissions for a canvas page is redirecting him to an authorization url, with a callback url linking back to your canvas page.
once the user returns he will either have a new singed_request with a valid user id and token, or the request will contain error information (typically -> the user did not approve your app)

the whole process is explained [this tutrial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)